# Eclipse Neon and Oxygen setExtended GridLayout can't cast to FillLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-oxygen

I have a big plug-in eclipse Indigo RCP program.
Trying to migrate to Oxygen and Java 8 (from 7) I get problems with all om my setExpanded(false) regarding GridLayouts.

I get a response similar to ...**GridLayout can not be casted to FillLayout**.
The strange thing is that this worked in Indigo. No changes to the code-base between the two versions. Apart from this Compact/Extend the program seems to work.

Any ideas??

Of course I can add the error-message but my question is if there are changes between indigo and Oxygen or even Neon and Oxygen that concern setExtend?

There is a bug report out there from 2014 but seems never to have been resoved.

stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-09-15 08:44:54.915
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.flushCache(FillLayout.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.requestLayout(Control.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite.reflow(ExpandableComposite.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section.reflow(Section.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite.internalSetExpanded(ExpandableComposite.java:893)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section.internalSetExpanded(Section.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite.toggleState(ExpandableComposite.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite.access$5(ExpandableComposite.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite$1.linkActivated(ExpandableComposite.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.lambda$3(AbstractHyperlink.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at com.myCompany.rcp.console.product.Application.start(Application.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Code:

```java
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) 

{
// Toolkit
FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
toolkit.setBorderStyle(SWT.NO);

// Base component
baseComp = toolkit.createComposite(parent);
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();       
layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
layout.marginHeight=0;
layout.marginWidth=0;
baseComp.setLayout(layout);
baseComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
m_searchRoiSection = toolkit.createSection(baseComp, Section.DESCRIPTION | Section.TWISTIE | Section.EXPANDED);
m_searchRoiSection.setActiveToggleColor(toolkit.getHyperlinkGroup().getActiveForeground());
m_searchRoiSection.setToggleColor(toolkit.getColors().getColor(IFormColors.SEPARATOR));
toolkit.createCompositeSeparator(m_searchRoiSection);
layout = new GridLayout();
layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
layout.verticalSpacing = 10;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 0;
m_searchRoiSection.setLayout(layout);
m_searchRoiSection.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
m_searchRoiSection.addExpansionListener(new ExpansionAdapter() 
{
public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) 
{
updateRoiSection();
}
});
m_searchRoiSection.setText("ROI");
m_searchRoiSection.setDescription("Select region of interest. Leave blank for any area.");
Composite searchRoiComp = toolkit.createComposite(m_searchRoiSection);
layout = new GridLayout();
layout.horizontalSpacing = 3;
layout.verticalSpacing = 3;
layout.marginHeight = 5;
layout.marginWidth = 5;
layout.numColumns = 3;
searchRoiComp.setLayout(layout);
// Create ROI search section contents
createRoiSearch(searchRoiComp);
m_searchRoiSection.setClient(searchRoiComp);        
m_searchRoiSection.setExpanded(false);
}
```

Comment: What is `setExtended? I, for one, have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: sorry for being unclear.

in org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets you can create sections that are expandable with a twistie icon. I use gridlayout and set the method setExpanded to false. This means the section is compact as starting point. 

My source is:

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
layout.horizontalSpacing = 3;
layout.verticalSpacing = 3;
layout.nuColumns = 3;

Then add the layout to a Composite named searchComposite.

searchComposite.setLayout(layout);

Then att this Composition to a Section.

Comment: 'then add layout' where? Edit your question and show us a proper [mcve]

Comment: Then att this Composition to a Section.
Section m_searchComposition.setClient(searchComposition);

Then comes the magic
m_searchComposition.setExpanded(false);

This line works in Indigo.
When migrating to Oxygen it stops working.

casting ...GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.Filldata
Only I have no parent as Filldata....

Comment: Sorry for being unclear again Im trying to get hang of stackoverflow forum as well. noob here

Comment: You need to show us the Stack Trace. Use the 'edit' link below the question to edit the queston to add additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
baseComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
```

is setting layout data on the base composite. This data is used by the `parent` control layout. The parent control is using `FillLayout` so `GridData` is not correct. You should just remove this line as you don't need any layout data for `FillLayout`.

`setExpanded` causes a `reflow` which redoes the layout of all controls so you are hitting this when you call `setExpanded`.

Also note:

```
layout = new GridLayout();
layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
layout.verticalSpacing = 10;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 0;
m_searchRoiSection.setLayout(layout);
```

`Section` does not support `setLayout` and is just ignoring this call.

Comment: You are fantastic! It solved the problem.
I don't understand why the parent is using FillLayout because I cant trace the parent-object (Im not familiar with the framework properly yet). But this was magic! Do you know why this worked in Indigo? have they changed something between Java7 and Java8?

Comment: This is nothing to do with Java versions. Eclipse internals were completely rewritten going from Eclipse 3 to 4 so it could be anything to do with that. As far as I remember the parent control passed to createPartControl has always used FillLayout.

Comment: ok. that's good to know. Still very strange that we have used it for so long in Indigo and it appeared now. Anyways, thank you very much for your help!